# Linking ObservableObject to DatePicker in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, datepicker, combine

I am new to Swift and all its frameworks. I have a JSON file with readings for each day of the year. I have made a `Decodable` struct for the reading and an `ObservableObject` class which stores the readings in an array. I have made the `ObservableObject` an `@EnvironmentObject` so it can be accessed in all views. Can I link the readings to the date picker so that selecting a date will take me to a detailed view?

```
import SwiftUI

struct CalendarView: View {
    // this is where ObserveableObject is required
    @EnvironmentObject var days: Days
    
    @State private var date = Date()
    
    let dateFormatter: DateFormatter = {
       let formatter = DateFormatter()
        // formatter.dateStyle = .long
        formatter.dateFormat = "LLLL d"
        return formatter
    }()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Select a date to read")
                .font(.largeTitle)
            
            DatePicker("Select a date", selection: $date, displayedComponents: .date)
                .datePickerStyle(GraphicalDatePickerStyle())
                .labelsHidden()
                .frame(maxHeight: 400)
            
            Text("\(date, formatter: dateFormatter)")
        }
        .navigationTitle("Datepicker")
    }
}

struct CalendarView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        CalendarView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Replace this with your Decodable object
class Day : ObservableObject{
    let id: UUID = UUID()
    var date: Date
    init( date: Date) {
        self.date = date
    }
}
class CalendarViewModel: ObservableObject, Identifiable {
    
    @Published var days: [Day] = []
    @Published var selectedDate: Date = Date()
    
    var filteredDay: Day?{
        days.filter({
            Calendar.current.isDate($0.date, equalTo: selectedDate, toGranularity: .day)
        }).first
    }
    
    init() {
        //Create sample Days you can remove this and populate your array with acual data
        for n in 1...30{
            days.append(Day(date: Date().addingTimeInterval(TimeInterval(60*60*24*n))))
            days.append(Day(date: Date().addingTimeInterval(TimeInterval(-60*60*24*n))))
        }
    }
}
struct CalendarView: View {
    @StateObject var vm: CalendarViewModel = CalendarViewModel()
    
    @State var isVisible: Bool = false
    let dateFormatter: DateFormatter = {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        // formatter.dateStyle = .long
        formatter.dateFormat = "LLLL d"
        return formatter
    }()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            ScrollView {
                Text("Select a date to read")
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                
                DatePicker("Select a date", selection: $vm.selectedDate, displayedComponents: .date)
                    .datePickerStyle(GraphicalDatePickerStyle())
                    .labelsHidden()
                    .frame(maxHeight: 400)
                
                Text("\(vm.selectedDate, formatter: dateFormatter)")
                
                if vm.filteredDay != nil{
                    NavigationLink(
                        destination: DayView(day: vm.filteredDay!),
                        isActive: $isVisible,
                        label: {
                            Text("View Day")
                        })
                }else{
                    Text("No results for selected day")
                }
                
            }
            .navigationTitle("Datepicker")
        }
    }
    
}
struct DayView:View {
    //Observe the actual Day here for changes
    @ObservedObject var day: Day
    let dateFormatter: DateFormatter = {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        // formatter.dateStyle = .long
        formatter.dateFormat = "LLLL d"
        return formatter
    }()
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Text(dateFormatter.string(from: day.date))
        }
    }
}
```